# How to call a function in dojo?

Tags: javascript, jsp, dojo

I have a checkbox tree where I need to restore the set of events on page load which was happening before page load upon click of the checkboxes of the tree.Can someone suggest me how can I call a function in dojo. I am trying to call dojo `function(_applyOnClickToAll)` on pageload but it is not getting called.

```
_applyOnClickAll: function{
logic to disable all remainingcheckboxes on clicking one checkbox
}
```

The `reloadcheckbox_status` function need to disable all the check-boxes on page load or refresh by calling the _applyOnclickAll function but it is not getting called.Can someone please suggest me where I am going wrong?

I tried to call the _applyOnclickAll() by two ways but neither of them worked `this._applyOnclickAll() and applyOnclickAll();` Where am I going wrong?

```
function reloadcheckbox_staus(){ 
for(var i = 0; i < checkbox.length; i++){
Widget.set('checked', true);
this._applyOnClickToAll();
}}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your _applyOnClickAll function should look like...

```
_applyOnClickAll = function() {
logic to disable all remainingcheckboxes on clicking one checkbox
}

reloadcheckbox_staus = function() { 
for(var i = 0; i < checkbox.length; i++){
Widget.set('checked', true);
_applyOnClickToAll();
}}
```

Comment: Hi Jason, I tried the above suggestions but on adding '=' before the function _applyOnClickAll = function() but on addition of = the tree itself stopped appearing. Can you please suggest if something else needs to be changed?

Comment: I think, your ":" is correct. I've never seen a JS function written with "=" before the function keyword unless it's assigned to a variable.